# iOS get buffer while recording audio and play buffer

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, buffer, record

I want to play on voice call speakers my sound while recording but i dont want to save in file this duration and get buffer as byte array for keep on voip service.

How to can i do this any ideas or framework for this situation.

Thank you.